# cv2 python color not working properly (drawing)

Tags: python, colors, geometry, drawing, opencv

I have some code that is supposed to draw a blue line coming out of a blue circle.

```
        cv2.circle(image, (x, y), 10, (255, 0, 0), -1)
        cv2.line(image, (x, y), (x, y+60), (255, 0, 0), 5)
```

the code above generates a white circle and a white line, so I thought maybe it's only taking the (255) out of the (255, 0, 0), and turns out I was right. For some reason, the color parameter takes an integer and not a color tuple like in the docs. I tried putting in (0, 255, 255) and it drew a black line as expected if it only took the first value (0). I tried also just putting a 0 not in a tuple, which gave the same results. Any help getting it to produce color?

Answer (score 0):

When making/loading the image make sure you're not loading it in grayscale mode,
or

```
image = np.zeros([1024, 1024, 1], dtype=np.uint8)
                              ^ change to 3
```